# Change subdomain to a hash

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I am not sure how to word this, but I basically want to do the following:

```
from: random.domain.com
to: domain.com/#!random

from: anything.domain.com/dur
to: domain.com/dur/#!anything
```

I guess I would need to modify the .htaccess file but I honest to God have no clue and I'm pretty sure at least one of the awesome fella's at Stackoverflow would know this by heart.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1#!%1 [L,R,NE]
```

Comment: Sadly that did not work :( It will just say the webpage is not available.